# Increase Rate Limit on Facebook Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

While figuring out how to use the Instagram Graph API for Hashtag searches I found out that the rate limit kind of makes it impossible for my use case to search hashtags. Maybe I just don't know the best practices for the Hashtag search so here is my use case:

A client wants an application to manage coupon/discounts initiatives for his clients. Each of those clients have a store and want to offer discounts for everyone posting on instagram with a store-specific hashtag. My client wants to create/update/delete stores in an application and define the hashtag for a store. Thats all done. Now I need to trigger hashtag searches for each store. And heres the problem:

There are 70 stores (at first, may be more in the future). Each store has a unique hashtag and wants to know who posts something with their hashtag. When someone posts with a hashtag the application should know after max. 20 seconds. This means triggering a hashtag search 70 times (because there are as many hashtags as there are stores) every 20 seconds (I know once I get the hashtag ID I can save it and don't need to search for the acutal term anymore, but I still need the newest media for the hashtag ID).

Thats one thing. The other thing is I can only query 30 different unique hashtags in a week (facebook api limitation). But I will need to query at least 70 different hashtags. And the stores don't want to create a facebook account and instagram business page, so they can oauth into my application just for that.

So at the moment the way of doing it is kind of create 70 fake-pseudo-accounts (one for each store) and use those acocunts to prevent hitting the rate limit. But I don't think this is the way facebook wants me to use the graph api.

In this post [Facebook API rate limit increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408119/facebook-api-rate-limit-increase) an answer from 2017 shows that there is a possibility to request a rate limit increase and in the linked picture is even the sentence "This is a page management app with few users but many calls". But more recent comments show that this is not possible anymore and I couldn't find any rate limit increase option in the developer portal.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408611/6315447 This answer even says there is no possibility anymore and If you hit the rate limit you're doing something you are not supposed to. But how should I use the API then?

Am I missing something? What is the best practice for such a use case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best practice in such case is to not do it because it is not allowed by Facebook Developer Policies: https://developers.facebook.com/devpolicy 3:2. And yes Facebook and Instagram uses the same Developer Policies. You are not allowed to reward someone for posting.

Comment: @WizKid But still. Assuming you just want to know the activity of your hashtag without any discount possibility, you'll still hit the rate limit. There must be a way for doing this, no?

Comment: So what is your usecase that is allowed by the policy? Maybe that is solvable in some completely different way?

Comment: @WizKid Theres a conference with multiple halls and each hall has its own topic. In front of the halls (entryway) there is a display that shows the recent instagram posts, tweets and so on tagged with the topic of the hall. This display should update in near-realtime (like 10-20 seconds) so visitors can see whats currently going on.